# ubuntu 18.04 - too long to show login

Tags: ubuntu, login, performance

it takes on average 2 minutes showing the splash screen before the login widget is made visible.

blame did not show anything suspicious (this is after removing splash and quiet optiona off in grub):

```
      6.384s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      1.024s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
       917ms fwupd.service
       898ms apparmor.service
       824ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       802ms ModemManager.service
       787ms lvm2-pvscan@8:1.service
       735ms udisks2.service
```

The last boot console message is "started user manager for uid 120"

and here is the long gap in the syslog:

```
Jul  3 14:11:42 maciek-ubuntu gdm-password]: GdmSession: Disposing session
Jul  3 14:11:42 maciek-ubuntu gdm-password]: GdmSession: Closing session
Jul  3 14:11:42 maciek-ubuntu gdm-password]: GdmSession: Stopping all conversations
Jul  3 14:13:02 maciek-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1708]: (II) Axis 0x1 value 5192 is outside expected range [1237, 4990]
Jul  3 14:13:02 maciek-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1708]: See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.10.4//absolute_coordinate_ranges.html for details
Jul  3 14:17:01 maciek-ubuntu CRON[3204]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul  3 14:17:22 maciek-ubuntu evolution-sourc[1895]: secret_service_search_sync: must specify at least one attribute to match
Jul  3 14:18:03 maciek-ubuntu gnome-shell[1851]: Object .Gjs_AppIndicatorIconActor__1 (0x55b93d91b780), has been already finalized. Impossible to set any property to it.
Jul  3 14:18:03 maciek-ubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1851]: == Stack trace for context 0x55b939fb8330 ==
Jul  3 14:18:03 maciek-ubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1851]: #0 0x7ffed7abc920 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:83 (0x7fa48c4b5de0 @ 87)
Jul  3 14:18:03 maciek-ubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1851]: #1 0x55b93a364f80 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/indicatorStatusIcon.js:93 (0x7fa4700c1098 @ 58)
Jul  3 14:18:03 maciek-ubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1851]: #2 0x7ffed7abdc80 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fa48c4b5de0 @ 71)
Jul  3 14:18:03 maciek-ubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1851]: #3 0x7ffed7abdd40 b   self-hosted:915 (0x7fa48c4f12b8 @ 367)
Jul  3 14:18:03 maciek-ubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1851]: #4 0x7ffed7abde30 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7fa48c4d3230 @ 386)
Jul  3 14:18:03 maciek-ubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1851]: #5 0x55b93a364ef8 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/appIndicator.js:190 (0x7fa4700a9cd0 @ 22)
Jul  3 14:18:03 maciek-ubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1851]: #6 0x7ffed7abf190 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fa48c4b5de0 @ 71)
Jul  3 14:18:03 maciek-ubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1851]: #7 0x55b93a364e50 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatcher.js:219 (0x7fa4700a9340 @ 225)
Jul  3 14:18:03 maciek-ubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1851]: #8 0x7ffed7ac04f0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fa48c4b5de0 @ 71)
Jul  3 14:18:03 maciek-ubuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1851]: #9 0x55b93a364dd8 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/extension.js:61 (0x7fa47009c4d8 @ 37)
```

Any suggestions?